# How to access a resource inside a jar inside webstart directory of webapp using JnlpDownloadServlet

Tags: web-applications, jnlp, java-web-start

I have deployed a swing GUI via [webstart-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/) and JnlpDownloadServlet to my webapp in a servlet container (Glassfish 3.0).
My GUI classes and resources are in a mygui-4.8.jar file that is in the webstart directory of my webapp along with the launch.jnlp file.

The app is able to start fine when access by its launch.jnlp url in a web browser:

http://localhost:8080/myserver/webstart/launch.jnlp

However when code in my webapp tries to access an image resource that is inside the mygui-4.8.jar file it is unable to retrieve it.

The code I use in the GUI to get the icon is:

URL iconURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/icons/Find.png");

Using a debugger I see that the iconURL.toString() is returning the following URL:

jar:http://localhost:8080/myserver/webstart/mygui.jar!/icons/Find.png

I notice that the version is missing on the jar file name (is mygui.jar instead of mygui-4.8.jar).

This seems to have something to do with the version handling in jnlp protocol.

Can any one tell me what how I should rewrite my client code to get at these resources inside the jar file? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I recommend you check the JNLP file (and main resources) using JaNeLA (http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: Having debugged this further I learned that the only get to the JnlpDownLoadServlet for the jar in questions mygui-4.8.jar is done once. Apparently javaws caches this jar on the client side and serves any requests to that jar localy without contacting the JnlpDownloadServlet. However, it appears that javaws does not seem to be processing the jar protocol correctly somehow for urls that access the Find.png file inside the jar. Is there a special trick to make this work?

Comment: This may be relevant... [http://rachel.sourceforge.net/tutorial2.html] will report back.

Comment: I tried the rachel tutorials approach with using the following but it did not change anything: URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory( new RachelUrlFactory() );

Answer (score 2):

Problem in solved!

The problem turned out to be a bug elsewhere in my code and had nothing to do with webstart, jnlp, or JnlpDownloadServlet. There was a flaw in how image resources where being accidentally pre-processed during the build process and as a result getting corrupted.

The correct way to reference resources was how I had it originally as follows:

```
String icon = "icons/Find.png"; //Notice no leading '/'
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(icon);            
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Above code works fine when the resource is inside a jar in the webstart directory of the webapp. It also works fine if it is found as a local file on the classpath. It works whether the app is running within javaws or as a standalone app outside javaws.